# Is it correct to say "Don't act too much when saying 'Hi Siri'"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

If you use iPhone, you probably know this Siri App in which you ask Siri robot a question and it will answer you.

Before you can ask a question, you have to say "**Hi Siri**" first or else the app will not start to work.

My daughter can say "**Hi Siri**" correctly without any problem in a normal conversation.

However, she is a bit nervous when she says "**Hi Siri**" to Siri. And she starts to "**act too much**" or "**say it unnaturally**" and as a result the app couldn't understand what she is saying.

Do we say "**she acts too much**" when she feels nervous and says a phrase with unnatural intonation like that?

**Or is there another phrase for it?**

Comment: I wouldn't say that she was **acting** (playing a part) when she speaks to the robot in an unnatural manner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain there's an absolute definition for this, but Siri does work best if you speak naturally to it, rather then be hesitant and over-precise. It even figures out accents pretty well.

My partner and I are both native English speakers. She has a precise, 'RP' accent, I have a comparatively rough Northern British accent. Siri understands me perfectly, yet she always struggles.
This is because she will over-enunciate and speak too slowly. I jokingly tell her Siri is neither a foreigner, deaf, nor an idiot & she doesn't need to treat it like one.

Me: Hey Siri, set timer for ten minutes.  …"Ten minutes & counting…"
Her: Hey Siri… … se t. tii merr. foor. TEN min. its. …"Here is what I could find on the internet for *tenmin*…"

Perhaps the phrase would be to 'over-enunciate' - to be more than accurate, to be so clipped in your precision as to become unintelligible to a dumb machine which is listening for natural speech patterns.
So, "Don't over-enunciate when speaking to Siri. Speak naturally."

Answer (score 0):

You sort of answered your own question:

> don't be so nervous/anxious when talking to Siri!

Being nervous or anxious can cause one to pronounce words wrongly.